# Files have .part automatically appended to them after downloading with selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

The code searches a website for a file and downloads it to a specified location. Everything works fine and the file is downloaded but (.part) is always appended to the end. This is my code:

```
def firefoxOptions():
    options = Options()

    options.headless = True
    options.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
    options.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
    options.set_preference("browser.download.dir", "PATH")
    options.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/csv")
    return options


def search():
    url = 'site_URL'
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=firefoxOptions()) 
    driver.get(url)

    time.sleep(3) #waits for the page to properly load

    driver.find_element(
        By.CSS_SELECTOR,
        "css_selector_first_button").click()

    time.sleep(1) #waits to load

#finds the download button and click it
    driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "css_selector_second_button").click()

    time.sleep(15) #waits for the download to finish
    print("download complete!")
    driver.quit() #file gets deleted when this is executed

search()
```

Note: I have to use Selenium because there is a lot of JavaScript. Here's a screenshot showing that the download button doesn't have a copy link (So I must use Selenium) [image: Download button doesn't have a copy link]

Comment: can you post the complete code and and the website url your tying to scrape

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1446633/why-do-browsers-append-a-part-extension-to-partial-downloads

Comment: Which version of Firefox and FirefoxDriver are you using? It seems like Firefox is not finishing the download. Maybe this is a problem with Firefox updating itself and the web driver is out of date? This is a wonky issue for sure.

Comment: @GregBurghardt I'm using Firefox V. 76.0.1 and geckodriver V. 0.26.0 for mac. I believe the download is finished judging from the size and the content of the file automatically downloaded and compared to the one downloaded manually.